# OTA Update Query

Tags: ota-update, localization

I recently flashed android 5.0 to my Samsung Galaxy S5, it was a polish build for the SM-G900F which successfully installed

Today I heard that an updated version was available for again people in Poland via OTA, I decided to check if it would work for me as I live in the UK

It turned out that I could in fact get the update, I was wondering how this is possible as the OTA updates have not been released for UK

Comment: You are running a Polish version, you will get notification for the Polish update. The device doesn't know/care where you are in the world physically. However, it may well not install as you might have a custom recovery stopping the OTA from installing.

Comment: Hi @RossC the update installed successfully, everything on the phone is official. Thanks for clearing that up though. One thought though, when a version is available for my region will I get a notification and be able to install it?

Comment: I doubt it to be honest. It's usually an update to your current firmware, and your current setup is a Polish ROM. Not to say you couldn't download the zip for the UK one from SamMobile and flash it in Odin, or just restore to stock ROM and update!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OTA updates can vary, and in my experience be a little unpredictable. However, since you have a Polish ROM, your geographical region is irrelevant to the Samsung firmware and you will receive an update notification. As per  your comment, since you are all stock then you can download and install the update.

If you want your official UK firmware there are 2 options really:

- Wait until the UK gets an update, download it from SamMobile and flash it via Odin. As per your current setup if the UK ROM gets an update you can install it as normal.
- Revert back to your most up to date stock ROM, and download the UK OTA when it is available. You will receive a notification as usual.

If you have a custom recovery you will need to revert to stock. It is the same as the second bullet point above: download the stock firmware and flash via Odin (PC) or Heimdall (Mac / *NIX).